# Can admob work on sdk 2.2? Can't get project to compile

Tags: android

In googles doc it says,

Requirements

Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).
The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml). This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum).

I'm a little confuse, it says that you need the latest version, and it also says it can run on a runtime of 1.5.  So does it really need sdk 1.5 or higher? Why do they say you must have the latest version?

I first made a app on 3.2 worked fine, then I tried 2.2. I got a error in the manifest file.  It was in the line that googles toturiol told you to add

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

The error was in android:configChanges.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uiMode needs API Level 8.

Some parameter you have mentioned in ConfigChanges are added after 2.2 Thats why you are getting Error.

You can make it work as follows.

Read requirement mentioned in AdMob carefully.

> Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're
>   compiling against 
>       at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13).
>       The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later 
>       (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your  AndroidManifest.xml).
>       This means you can develop with the latest version of the Android SDK and your app will still run on an earlier Android version (1.5 minimum).

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering my question, I'm a little confuse. do you mean set android:minsdkversion to 1.5? you have 3?

Comment: Yes it is mentioned!! But if you are targeting audience who have android 2.2 or greater then you can set minVersion accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot. You have to use SDK 4.0 and set min SDK version to 8.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK and the runtime are two separate (though related things). The SDK is the Software Development Kit. It's what you use to develop (and compile) with. The runtime is what actually runs on the device. The directions are actually pretty clear:

> Make sure you have the latest copy of the Android SDK and that you're compiling against at least Android v3.2 (set target in default.properties to android-13)

Make sure your target SDK level is at least 13.

> The Google AdMob Ads SDK for Android requires a run-time of Android 1.5 or later (set android:minSdkVersion to at least 3 in your AndroidManifest.xml).

To ensure that this only shows in Google Play for devices 1.5 and later, set `minSdkVersion` to at least 3.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering my question.  I'm a little confuse. Your saying that in dev I will be running my program as a android 3.2 sdk.  But the APK file produce using the sdk 3.2 can run under a 2.2???? I'm assuming I will have to mke sure I do not use any lib that are only in  2.1. also is the only way to test it on a 2.2 android is to download into a device? can i use the emulated some how to test it??? I find this confusing.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run an APK targeting 3.2 to run on 2.2 as long as you don't use any APIs not supported/implemented in 2.2. Generally all versions are forwards compatible, if it works in 2.1 it'll work in 2.2 and it'll work in 3.2. Newer versions are mostly supersets of the old (+ non-API-breaking fixes).